Recommended iterative numeric solver for generalized eigenvalue problem?
I have a generalized eigenvalue problem of the form $Av=\lambda Bv$, with the following conditions:

$A$ is symmetric, but not sure if it is positive-definite.
$B$ is diagonal with positive entries
$A$ is large and dense, so storing $A$ itself is expensive, but evaluating $x\mapsto Ax$ is cheap.
It is known in advance $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue, and I only want the eigenvector corresponding to this eigenvalue.
Exact solution is not required, an approximate one will do. Efficiency is preferred over accuracy.

Given these conditions, what is the most appropriate numeric solver?

Given your $B$ I'd transform the problem to $B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}$ which is a standard, symmetric, eigenvalue problem.

Do you know if $\lambda=1$ is the largest or smallest eigenvalue (algebraically or in modulus)? If this is the case you can use one of the many iterative solvers like Lanczos

@lcv Unfortunately no, $\lambda=1$ may not be the largest or smallest eigenvalue.

Your situation appears extraordinary. How can it be cheap to evaluate matrix vector products $Ax$, but (too?) expensive to store $A$. Please expand this point significantly and include the dimensions of your problem. If your hardware is unusual, then add a short description of this as well.

@CarlChristian Not really extraordinary. This is because $Ax$ can be accelerated by fast multipole method. These cases appear frequently in $N$-body interaction problems, and mine is a variant of them.

Do you have the ability to solve linear systems of the form $Ax=b$ by utilizing the underlying application? Do you have an interval that contains the spectrum of $A$?

@CarlChristian I think $Ax=b$ can be solved with conjugate gradients, but I am not sure how stable it would be. And no, I don't have an interval containing the spectrum
